# problem while sending Multipart image, video & param to server

Tags: swift, image, parameters, multipart, moya

I am using moya and want to send image, video & parameters dictionary of [String : Any]

for parameters I am writing

```
*for (key, value) in param {
            multipartFormData.append(Moya.MultipartFormData(provider: .data((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) ?? Data()) , name : key))
            }*
```

but i am getting this error as my param dictionary contains String & Int as well

```
*-[__NSCFNumber dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance*
```

Please suggest how can i resolve this?

Comment: using AmaloFire ?

Answer (score 0):

to add image inside `multipartFormData` you could try something like this line.

```
  MultipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "1.png")!, 1)!, withName: "photos[1]", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
```

using `Alamofire` a full example is something like this

```
let parameters = [
            "param1" :        "1000",
            "param2":      "Murat Akdeniz",
            "param3":        "xxxxxx"]

let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "1.png")!,1)



    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in
        //    multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "user", fileName: "user.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

            for (key, value) in parameters {
            let value = "\(value)"  //Added this line to use [String:Any ] param types

                MultipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }

    MultipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "1.png")!, 1)!, withName: "photos[1]", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    MultipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "1.png")!, 1)!, withName: "photos[2]", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")


}, to: "youURL") { (result) in

    switch result {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):

        upload.responseJSON { response in
            print(response.result.value)
        }

    case .failure(let encodingError): break
        print(encodingError)
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you, but in my case i have parameter  disctionary of type [String : AnyObject] so having problem in encoding. From your code  for (key, value) in parameters {
                MultipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            } this part wont work

Comment: What are the possible types in AnyObject

Comment: String, int & double

Comment: can't be Int, because Int dose not confirm to AnyObject type

Comment: may [string: Any?]

Comment: @AanchalChaurasia i added an extra line for you try it

Comment: Yeah that can be done but at server end they need data as Int, String & double so converting in string is not an option for me.

Comment: there server will convert it back as needed, try it and check response if there is a problem with error tell me what is it